# CSS3: how to put something at the top of second column?

Tags: html, css

I have a two column text layout of fixed width and height, implemented with `-{moz,webkit}-column-*` stuff (i.e. text freely flows from one column to another).

How do I put a image to the top of the second column, aligned to the right (i.e. to the outer border of the text), so that the text in the column flows around that image?

JS is OK (but I'd prefer to do without it). Should work at least in latest Chrome and latest FF. Mobile Safari is desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky indeed, and even with JS I can't think of an optimal solution. Anyway, as Last Rose Studios says, you can use the column-break property on the image to force the image to be on the top of the second column always, as shown on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STxjD/). However, this is a valid solution for webkit only, as firefox doesn't support `column-break` property yet afaik.

Taking this and the fact that the layout has fixed width and height into consideration, I think the best solution is just making two divs acting as columns as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STxjD/2/). Not the perfect solution, but I think the multi column layout is not enough for what you want, at least for the moment.

EDIT:

If you divide your text in paragraphs, you can make them flow from one column to the next one like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FX9JG/) using jQuery, based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009670/flow-2-columns-of-text-automatically-with-css#3039054).

Comment: There is a workaround for FF (at least for split prevention, which may be enough here): FF does not support `column-break`, but it does not split `inline-block` elements.

Comment: About using two divs: any ready-to use code to make the text flow in this case?

Comment: I'm afraid that FF workaround won't be useful in here since it won't make the image 'jump' to the next column. I can't think of any non-JS method to achieve that, but if you divide your text in paragraphs, you can make them flow from one column to the next one like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FX9JG/) using jQuery, based on [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009670/flow-2-columns-of-text-automatically-with-css#3039054). I don't know if it suits your needs, as it's not probably the answer you were looking for, but I think this is as close as I can get :P

Comment: Looks like what I need. Please incorporate this in your answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

take a look at css3 specs for it at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-breaks it might help

Comment: Thanks, but the question is — where to put that box with the image? I suppose it should be put at the right place by JS code, but where to?..

Comment: For the record: at the time of writing, AFAIK, this solution only works in Chrome. See also comments to the other question.