# How to make definitions of definition list in two columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, multiple-columns

I'm trying to list movie info, and I want the "cast" list to have two columns, instead of one long column to make better use of horizontal space.

A similar question was asked here:[Multi-column definition list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110794/multi-column-definition-list)

but that is NOT the same question I have. That user was trying to split the dt into two columns, and I want to split one set of the dd into two columns.  Here's my code:

```
div><h3>
    <dl>
      <dt>Director:</dt>
        <dd>Person A</dd><br>
      <dt>Writer:</dt>
        <dd>Person B</dd><br>
      <dt>Cast:</dt>
        <dd>Person C</dd>
        <dd>Person D</dd>
        <dd>Person E</dd>
        <dd>Person F</dd>
        <dd>Person G</dd>
        <dd>Person H</dd>
        <dd>Person I</dd>
    </dl></h3>
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```
dl {
border: 3px double #ccc;
padding: 0.5em;
}
dt {
float: left;
font-weight: 400;
}
dd {
margin-left: 125px;
font-weight: 300;
}
```

Again, I'm looking to make just the cast list two columns.  Any and all help is appreciated!

I'm totally open to using other lists or non-definition lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go using CSS only, using a float and clear approach:

```
dt {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    background: lightgreen;
}
dd {
    width: 50%; 
    padding: 15px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    background: skyblue; 
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/luminancedesign/wngjs3wg/

Comment: I had to add a wrappr div with .wrapper `dl, .wrapper dt, .wrapper dd` in place of the `*` universal selector in for the first class to get the intended result, becuase I didn't want to apply those styles to the whole page. +1 for an easy to apply solution.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can simply float the dd, like this:

```
dd{width:50%; float:left}
```

if you're looking to use dd, I think this is the closes to a solution you will find. However, if you're open to use other techniques, like regular lists, p, block elements, etc, you can use column-count (doesn't work in dd) . See more info at [column count property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp)

Comment: And be sure to contain the floated `<dd>`s, either with the [clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) on the `<dt>` or by using `dt {overflow: hidden;}` in your CSS.

Comment: yes, of course, but I think that's a given in any floated element, hence why I didn't mention it, but 

`dl, dt{clear:both}` 

should be enough

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. I had better luck with your column count link, but still no success. You'll see in my CSS that I floated the dt, and it's affecting the columns for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
dl { position: relative; }
dd { margin-left: 100px; }
dt { position: absolute; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66ge3wj5/)

Not a very good way, but the only way I can think of with this kind of html and without any js.